# UDP Packets Out of Order - What is the Likelihood in Uncongested Connection

Tags: ethernet, udp

We have two pieces of equipment in the same room communicating over a dedicated Ethernet LAN connection that is not shared by any other equipment. The communication protocol is UDP.

I've been listening to concerns about the UDP packets being received and processed out of order. I don't understand how that would happen in such a dedicated connection. Can someone tell me if this is a real thing to be concerned about, and if so, how does this happen?

Related - we can deal with  packet loss, but I don't see how packet loss would occur under these conditions either. If they can, would someone explain?

For practical reasons, we are intentionally not using TCP. TCP is not an option.

Comment: Were those concerns stated specifically in regards to your dedicated connection?

Comment: The concerns were mentioned with an awareness that this was the type of connection we are using. I'm not sure it was factored into their expression of the concern or are they just parroting back a general property of UDP that might be irrelevant in this particular case.

Comment: with UDP, you get to decide what you app needs, because you have to program those features into your application layer. if you need a means to detect order, request resends, detect errors, etc, you have to write that in

Comment: In a point-to-point setup, you should not be concerned about out-of-order delivery. Out-of-order delivery might occur if the Ethernet frames take different paths to the final destination. Packet loss could still occur as communication channel are typically not error free. Completely losing any trace of the frame is unlikely, but the need to verify the integrity of the datagram is still essential, and responding with an Ack/Nak and retransmission need to be considered. You might investigate Reliable UDP if the data is "valuable" or difficult to replace.